# iOS7 - popToRootViewControllerAnimated not doing anything

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, poptoviewcontroller

I have looked around but haven't found a satisfying answer. My problem is that whenever I call  `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)` it is not doing anything. When I NSLog it, it logs `(null)`. 
Let me back up a bit here. I have a table view controller that has a list of things, at the navigation bar up top there is an option to add and that takes me to a new view controller with a segue "Present as PopOver" which gets rid of the principal or main navigation bar. So I made one manually and added 2 bar button items "Cancel" and "Add". When "Cancel" is tapped, it should take the user back to the table view controller and discard changes, when "Add" button is tapped, it should also take user back to the previous table view controller with the changes. But it's not doing anything.

Here is my code.

```
- (IBAction)cancelButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
UINavigationController * navigationController = self.navigationController;
NSLog(@"%@", navigationController);
NSLog(@"cancel tapped though");
ListingTableViewController *rootController = [[ListingTableViewController alloc] init];
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[navigationController pushViewController:rootController animated:YES];
}
```

As far as the segue, this view controller is not connected to anything, or should I connect it? This is a noobish question indeed. Here is my xcode screenshot.

Check this link for the screenshot of the storyboard
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqnCF.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call

```
- (IBAction)cancelButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    NSLog(@"cancel tapped though");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

instead of `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` because your VC presented and not pushed!

Answer (score 1):

When presenting a view, you are not pushing it in your navigation controller, but having it presented. To dismiss it, try using `[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]`.